# Including seconds when using strptime with examples such as 10-10-2010 00:00:00

Tags: r, datetime, posixct, strptime

I have had a good hunt around and sure this has to have been answered before but I cant seem to find any help!

I have a series of times in a data frame, some of which have the following time stamp in the following format:

```
Date <- '2018-10-10'
Time <- '00:00:00'
```

When I use the `strptime` function it returns only the date, it removes the `00:00:00`, see below:

```
datetime <- strptime(paste(Date,Time),
                     format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                     tz = 'GMT')

> datetime
[1] "2018-10-10 GMT"
```

if for example it was `Time <- 00:00:01` it would return

```
> datetime
[1] "2018-10-10 00:00:01 GMT"
```

Does anyone know a way of ensuring the output for `00:00:00` instances are displayed. Desired output:

```
"2018-10-10 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Many thanks!!

Jim

Comment: Use `strftime` with `datetime` to create a character string witth a specific format.

Comment: Under the hood `print.POSIXct` calls `format`. From `?format`: "The default for the format methods is `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` if any element has a time component which is not midnight, and `"%Y-%m-%d"` otherwise.".

Comment: Cheers, I did have a good luck I didnt even think about calling it 'midnight'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `datetime` and hit `<Enter>`, R will use a/the suitable print method to display `datetime`. Just because `datetime` returns `"2018-10-10 GMT"` doesn't mean that `datetime` has forgotten about the seconds.

To ensure a consistent format of your `POSIXlt` object, you could use `format`

```
format(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", usetz = T)
#[1] "2018-10-10 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Similar for case 2

```
Date <- '2018-10-10'
Time <- '00:00:01'
datetime <- strptime(paste(Date,Time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = 'GMT')
format(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", usetz = T)
#[1] "2018-10-10 00:00:01 GMT"
```

---

### Sample data

```
Date <- '2018-10-10'
Time <- '00:00:00'
datetime <- strptime(paste(Date,Time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = 'GMT')
```

Comment: awesome! worked a treat cheers, I thought it would be hiding there somewhere, but it doesnt print it during write.csv either. Many thanks